# Split list of lists by pattern

Tags: python, list, split, slice

I would like to split a list of lists by checking if the first element of each child list is '0', i.e.

```
original_list = [[0,ab],[1,cd],[1,ef],[0,gh],[1,ij]]
```

And I want my resulting list to be:

```
result = [[ab,cd,ef],[gh,ij]]
```

I imagine I will need to use dictionary, but what is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: StackOverflow is node a code writing forum. Please show your work so we can help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Put together a working solution first.

Comment: I did try many things (got very close by using a flag) but got stuck, that's why I asked for help. Anyway, will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, this could solve your problem:

```
original_list = [[0,'ab'],[1,'cd'],[1,'ef'],[0,'gh'],[1,'ij']]

result = []
temp = []
checker = 0
for item in original_list:
    if item[0] >= checker:
        checker = item[0]
    else:
        result.append(temp)
        checker = 0
        temp = []
    temp.append(item[1])

result.append(temp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Boris, that works! The checker was the bit I was missing.